# Why is the "AWS Resources" tab in cloud9 no longer showing up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I am following the following video to create and edit an AWS Lambda function.

"Using AWS Cloud9 to Edit, Debug, and Deploy a Lambda Function"

youtube.COM/watch?v=ynmU5qy82Vg

For some reason, my UI does not have the tab "AWS Resources". How do I adjust this? I am the admin to the instance.

Answer (score 2):

The UI has slightly changed since the recording of the video. The AWS Resources tab now is a Lambda symbol (λ) at the right edge of the IDE (see Figure 1). If you can't find it, it can be activated by checking **AWS Resources** in the **Window** menu (see Figure 2).

[image: AWS Resources Tab]

Figure 1: AWS Resources tab

[image: How to activate the AWS Resources tab]

Figure 2: How to activate the AWS Resources tab

Comment: Turns out AWS is updating the interface, and environments created after Dec 2020 will automatically use the new interface which will including AWS toolkit.

You can turn AWS resources tab on by turning AWS toolkit off, in the cloud9 preferences - - > AWS settings and AWS resources. So they actually removed it fully...

Comment: Thanks @MattM, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

@MattM @DennisTraub Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I was going round in circles and the AWS documentation has NOT been updated to reflect the new UI.

For anyone else out there who may be confused, please see the new path:
[image: AWS C9 path to create new Application]

Comment: This came out really blurry. Can you please repost?

Comment: @MattM sorry about that - you need to: (1) Click on the AWS icon (2) click on the icon in the top left hand corner of the resulting menu (3) from the pop-out menu, choose the lambda option